# 3x3 2D array test for Magic Square with Java

Tags: java

So I was given a task to write a program that checks whether a square is a magic square and, if so, that prints its magic number.

The code I wrote just works, if the square is indeed a magic square, but it doesn't give the "false" message when the numbers typed by the user are not a magic square.

The output is how it should be, when it is a magic square, but when it's not, the output is always magic number: 0.

Here is the Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MagischesQuadrat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] square = new int[3][3];
        Scanner keyScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Read in square
        System.out.println("Please enter 9 numbers and confirm with Enter");
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
                square[i][j] = keyScan.nextInt();
            }
        }

        boolean magic = true;
        int magicNum = 0;
        
        
        // TODO: Check the square and set the variables magic and magic number to the correct value.
        int a = square[0][0] + square[0][1] + square[0][2];
        int b = square[1][0] + square[1][1] + square[1][2];
        int c = square[2][0] + square[2][1] + square[2][2];
        
        int d = square[0][0] + square[1][0] + square[2][0];
        int e = square[0][1] + square[1][1] + square[2][1];
        int f = square[0][2] + square[1][2] + square[2][2];
        
        if (a == b && a == c && a == d) {
            magic = true;
            magicNum = a;
        }
        
        // Output of the result
        if (magic) {
            System.out.println("Magic number: "+magicNum);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not magic");
        }
        keyScan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try initializing the magic=false.

Comment: Why are you calculating `e` and `f` if you do not use them?

Comment: @km1 Thank you. that actually solved the problem. Is there an explenation for that? I really don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: The default case should be that any given square is **not** a magic square, so `magic` should be initialized with `false`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I used it in a previous attemp to solve the issue and just didn't delet it. But your right, I don't need it.

Comment: @QBrute Oh, ok I see. Thanks!

Comment: No, I believe you **do** need these variables.

Comment: Also, you are only checking rows and columns. What about the diagonals?

Comment: Yes, you do need `e` and `f` and also `g` and `h` that contain the diagonal sums, as @PM77-1 and @km1 mentioned. All of these also need to be equal to `a`. --- A tip: Try using more descriptive variable names like `topRow` instead of `a`, `middleRow` instead of `b` and so on. For your task it's sufficient enough, but for larger code it gets really messy and confusing when you call your variables just after the letters of the alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if (a == b && a == c && a == d) {
    magic = true;
    magicNum = a;
}
```

with:

```
magic = a == b && a == c && a == d;
magicNum = a;
```

Comment: Funny! with that replacement it is not necessary to change boolean magic = true;
Thank you!

Comment: In fact, you can initialize both variables in the same place: `boolean magic = a == b && a == c && a == d;` and `int magicNum = a;`. You don't need them before.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried that after it worked. Thank you for your help!